# Develop mobile web apps with Angular

Tags: angular, mobile

I am a little bit confused conserning building mobile web apps with Angular ang Angular Material.
My requirement is to build a simple mobile app without access any of the mobile phone - so I have just to create a CRUD mobile web app
Is it possible to build this mobile web app only with Angular or do I also need Ionic or any other additional framework.
I would be glad if someone could give me any hint in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to build a *web* application, you don't need Ionic, Angular will do just fine.

Comment: Do you have any hint how to start? Thanks a lot.